# Почему в visual c# в проекте Windows Form изменяется массив, который не должен изменяться?

Tags: windows, c#, winforms, массивы

Код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            //создаем и заполняем первый массив
            ArrayList ArrayOne = new ArrayList();
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
                ArrayOne.Add(i);

            //Создаем новый массив, и копируем в него содержимое первого
            ArrayList ArrayCopy = new ArrayList();
            ArrayCopy = ArrayOne;

            //Создаем третий массив и заполняем его с помощью функции, в которую передаем второй массив
            ArrayList arrayResult = new ArrayList(); 
            arrayResult = function(ArrayCopy);

            //что находится в ArrayOne после функции
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                MessageBox.Show("массив после функции " + ArrayOne[i].ToString());
        }

        ArrayList function(ArrayList ar)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                ar[i] = i*i;

            return ar;
        }
```

И почему то при выводе видно, что ArrayOne принял значения 1, 4, 9... Почему так происходит?

Comment: Вы не копируете во второй массив содержимое первого, а заменяете ссылку на него.
Прочитайте какую-нибудь книжку про C# ([такую, например][1]), чтобы не возникало таких вопросов.


  [1]: http://www.dialektika.com/books/978-5-8459-1699-0.html

Comment: А как можно скопировать?

Comment: копировать в шарпе вроде .clone() 
А что вы ожидали от вашего кода? Почему он не должен изменяться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //Создаем новый массив, и копируем в него содержимое первого
        ArrayList ArrayCopy = new ArrayList();
        ArrayCopy = (ArrayList)ArrayOne.Clone();
```

в вашем решении вы просто присвоили указатель ArrayOne указателю ArrayCopy соотвественно два указателя на один обьект. Когда прошли по указателю ArrayCopy  это было равнозначно проходу по ArrayOne